# Django-compressor and template tags in Django

Tags: javascript, django, templates, compression, django-compressor

Recently I have tried Django-Compressor. It's awesome and i like it too much, but i am having some troubles with offline compression (`COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True`) and template tags.

I have `{{ django_vars }}` and `{% django_tags %}` inside my JS code and i guess Google Clousure compiler (the filter what i'm using with Django-Compressor) doesn't know to identify them. In fact, I think Django template structures like `{% if something %}` are deleted.

How can i do to keep all this template vars/tags in my code JS after compressing?

Thanks mates.

**Edit**:
Finally, i discovered all problems that i got using `COMPRESS_OFFLINE`, they all occurred due to a bug. They were not about Django syntax inside of JS code. The bug always appeared when you tried to compress JS code inside of a file .html, not a external JS. It failed with all parsers and all compilers/compressors.

Now, although i like more django-compressor than django-pipeline, i'm using this last one. At this moment, no problem reported with compression.

Thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that? JS compiler of Django Compressor gets into work *AFTER* template nodes are rendered, IMO. Thus the `{{ django_vars }}` or `{% django_tags %}` are already replaced by their outputs in templates before being compressed.

If `{{ django_vars }}` or `{% django_tags %}` are changed per-view/template. It can not be compress to one piece of code. You'd better to move those parts from main JS code blocks to  JS block and compress it separately.

Comment: Doing some tests with offline compression i can see Google Clousure compiler compress and obfuscate code without Django template syntax right well, but in case there are any Django syntax in JS code it fails. I was looking for a solution about Google Clousure ignores Django syntax like it will be a comment (it would be awesome in compress inline mode) but i have not found anything. I'm guessing i'll have to adapt my JS code to separate all Django syntax from it. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RubénJiménez wait, do you mean that you want to have something like `{% foo %}` in the compressed file?

Comment: No, of course. I'm compressing all in inline mode ({% compress js inline %}, all the code inside .html files). So i want Google Clousure ignores Django syntax. This way, i can keep all my Django vars/tags inside my JS code (like original uncompressed JS code). To sum up, i need a filter which tells to Google Clousure (or other compiler like YUI) ignores all Django syntax and manage it like it will be a comment inside the code.