# Simple way to minify/scramble Django js

Tags: javascript, django, minify, scramble

There is a simple way to minify and/or obfuscate JS that it's present in my django templates?

I'm also using template variables and templates tag into js, so, the standard uglifyjs or similar are not fitting my original request.

Anything to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found django compressor very easy to use. In thirty minutes I'm done https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/
Maybe this could help for template tags and variables [Django-compressor and template tags in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172329/django-compressor-and-template-tags-in-django)

Comment: Even if i use whitenoise module?

Comment: if you use compressor on offline mode this shouldn't be a problem. Simple googling of "django compressor white noise" leads to similar questions. I think you should spend an hour reading the doc and trying django-compressor.